# How to write a generic method to handle multiple state changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods

I'm building an exercise tracker app in React.

Right now, I'm building the CreateExercise component to submit a form, so I need to update the states of each value. In order to do so, I created methods to handle those changes (onChangeUsername, onChangeDescription, onChangeDuration etc...) but I don't really like to repeat methods like this.

How to write a more generic method to handle this task ?

```
class CreateExercise extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      description: '',
      duration: 0,
      date: new Date(),
      users: []
    }
  }

  onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeDescription = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeDuration = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      duration: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeDate = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      date: date
    });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const exercise = {
      username: this.state.username,
      description: this.state.description,
      duration: this.state.duration,
      date: this.state.date
    }
    console.log(exercise);

    window.location = '/';
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h3>Create New Exercise Log</h3>
        <form onSubmit={ this.onSubmit }>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <select 
              ref='userInput'
              required
              className='form-control'
              value={ this.state.username }
              onChange={ this.onChangeUsername }
            >
              { this.state.users.map((user) => (
                <option key={user} value={user}>{user}</option>
                ))
              }
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Description:</label>
            <input 
              type='text'
              required
              className='form-control'
              value={ this.state.description }
              onChange={ this.onChangeDescription}
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Duration:</label>
            <input 
              type='text'
              className='form-control'
              value={ this.state.duration }
              onChange={ this.onChangeDuration }
            />
          </div>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <label>Date:</label>
            <div>
              <DatePicker 
                selected={ this.state.date }
                onChange={ this.onChangeDate }
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='form-groupe'>
            <input 
              type='submit'
              value='Create Exercise Log'
              className='btn btn-primary'
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CreateExercise;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [partial application](https://kyleshevlin.com/just-enough-fp-partial-application), create a function in your component that takes a field name, and returns a function that sets the state:

```
onChangeValue = field => e => {
  this.setState({
    [field]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
onChangeUsername = onChangeValue('username');

onChangeDescription = onChangeValue('description');

onChangeDuration = onChangeValue('duration');
```

You extend the idea further to support the `onChangeDate` as well:

```
onChangeValue = (field, valueTransformer = e => e.target.value) => e => {
  this.setState({
    [field]: valueTransformer(e.target.value)
  });
};
```

This doesn't change the other `on` functions, since the default is to get `e.target.value`. To use `onChangeDate` we can now change the `valueTransformer`:

```
onChangeDate = onChangeValue('date', v => v);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `name` for the `HTML` element, and use that to set value:

```js
onChange = e => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

corresponding JSX element:

```html
<input
  type="text"
  name="description"
  required
  className="form-control"
  value={this.state.description}
  onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```